# Как оформить предложение со словами «цитирую» и «конец цитаты»?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

Как правильно продолжить предложение?

1. — Он сказал, что, цитирую, поёт она хорошо, конец цитаты.
2. — Он сказал, что, цитирую: поёт она хорошо — конец цитаты.

Answer (score 1):

Речь может здесь идти только о *воспроизведении устной речи* (прямая речь персонажа и т. п.), где неприменима пунктуация в виде однозначно расположенных кавычек, - в изначально письменном тексте слова "цитирую" и (особенно) "конец цитаты" бесполезны. Начало и конец цитирования можно обозначить, например, так:

> — Он сказал, что (цитирую) "поёт она хорошо" - конец цитаты.

Answer (score 1):

Отталкиваемся от базовых предложений.
Он сказал: «Поёт она хорошо». (Оформление как собственно прямой речи.)
Он сказал, что «поёт она хорошо». (Цитата является частью предложения.)

Я бы написала так.
— Он сказал, цитирую: «Поёт она хорошо». Конец цитаты.
— Он сказал, что, цитирую, «поёт она хорошо». Конец цитаты.
— Он сказал, цитирую, что «поёт она хорошо». Конец цитаты. [поменьше запятых]

> — Мы спрашивали Вексли об этом, и он сказал, цитирую: «Вы об этом узнаете скоро. Когда помрете». Конец цитаты (Д. Клавелл. Король крыс).
>
> — Нет, предложили. Вы сказали, цитирую: «Я заплачу вам втрое больше, только, пожалуйста, ради бога, замолчите». Конец цитаты (Д. Шелвис. Нежданная страсть).
>
> — Он сказал, я цитирую, что «любой может купить знание по цене финансовой газеты или получить бесплатно от биржевого маклера, который пожелает выдать его в качестве приманки для новых клиентов» (Виктор О'Коннелл. Сын Орла).