# Как обособить "цитирую"?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата, оформление-цитат

Как верно? Думаю, так.

`Бизнесмен на встрече с журналистами сказал, цитирую: «Успех — это 1 % таланта и 99 % труда».`

А так? Верно ли я расставил знаки? Думаю, здесь двоеточие нельзя, поскольку пррблемы будут с изъяснительным придаточным.

`Бизнесмен на встрече с журналистами сказал, что, цитирую, «Успех — это 1 % таланта и 99 % труда».`

А можно ли оформить вставкой с тире и перед вторым тире поставить двоеточие (необычно, редкость!)?

`Бизнесмен на встрече с журналистами сказал — цитирую: — «Успех — это 1 % таланта и 99 % труда».`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Покрутила-повертела и решила, что первое предложение написано правильно:
*Бизнесмен на встрече с журналистами сказал, цитирую: «Успех — это 1 % таланта и 99 % труда»* (собственно цитирование, оформлено как прямая речь).

Слово "цитирую" здесь и других конструкциях является вводным — оно нуждается в обособлении и его, теоретически, можно изъять из предложений.

•• Во втором предложении я бы встроенную цитату написала со строчной буквы:
*Бизнесмен на встрече с журналистами сказал, что, цитирую, **«успех** — это 1 % таланта и 99 % труда».*

••• В третьем предложении второе тире (после двоеточия) не нужно; обособление вводного слова с помощью тире возможно (нечасто, конечно же, но встречается):
*Бизнесмен на встрече с журналистами сказал — цитирую: «Успех — это 1 % таланта и 99 % труда».*

Примеры (на все случаи):

*— Ты **сказала, цитирую:** «Присмотрелась бы хорошенько к толстосумам, на которых пашу, и подбросила им приманку». Вспомнила?* (Джеймс Хэдли Чейз. Осиное гнездо);

*Когда он передавал бразды правления следующему директору АКБ, он **сказал, что, цитирую, «возможно**, рано или поздно вы столкнётесь с загадочным случаем...* (Дмитрий Луговой. Необъяснимое);

*Двадцать семь минут назад ты **сказал — цитирую:** «Это ко всем относится!..»* (Роберт Хайнлайн. Число зверя).

P. S. Вот тут еще есть решения по схожему вопросу ([Как оформить предложение со словами «цитирую» и «конец цитаты»?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460223/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B/460225#460225)).